# Is it possible to make a function that takes a call to another function as a lambda expression and returns the result?

Tags: c#

I want to make a universal function that will add some action to the execution of any other function. As an example, some action is measuring execution time

```
void Func1()
{
    //doing something
}
Tuple<float, float[]> Func2(int x, List<float> list)
{
    float val1 = list[x];
    list.RemoveAt(x);
    float[] val2 = list.ToArray();
    return new Tuple<float, float[]>(val1, val2);
}
returnType? CommonFunc(Action action)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    var res = action();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Trace.WriteLine($"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    return res;
}
void Main()
{
    var func1Res = CommonFunc(() => Func1());
    List<float> floats = new List<float>() { 1.1f, 2.0f, 0, 4f };
    var func2Res = CommonFunc(() => Func2(1, floats));
}
```

What type of return value should I specify for a universal function? And this code is incorrect: `var res = action();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Func<T>` instead of Action if you want your function to return a value. `Func<T>` is a delegate that represents a method taking zero parameters and returning a value of type T. You can then use it with the `CommonFunc` method.

Sample code you can try:

```
void Func1()
{
    // doing something
}

Tuple<float, float[]> Func2(int x, List<float> list)
{
    float val1 = list[x];
    list.RemoveAt(x);
    float[] val2 = list.ToArray();
    return new Tuple<float, float[]>(val1, val2);
}

T CommonFunc<T>(Func<T> function)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    T result = function();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Trace.WriteLine($"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    return result;
}

void Main()
{
    var func1Res = CommonFunc(() => Func1());

    List<float> floats = new List<float>() { 1.1f, 2.0f, 0, 4f };
    var func2Res = CommonFunc(() => Func2(1, floats));
}
```

`CommonFunc` is now a generic method that takes a `Func<T>` instead of an Action. The `T` in `Func<T>` represents the return type of the function. This allows you to use `CommonFunc` with functions that return values. The result variable is of type T, and it captures the return value of the provided function

Ref :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-8.0